# Plotting precision recall curve for multiple algorithms

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I wanted to plot a single precision recall curve for the three algorithms that I make use of for my text classification. I'm quite a beginner so can someone tell me how can I add that functionality in my existing code.

```
nb_classifier = MultinomialNB()
svm_classifier = LinearSVC()
lr_classifier = LogisticRegression(multi_class="ovr")
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(df_train.data, df_train.label, test_size=0.2 , stratify = df_train['label'])
vect = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english', max_features=10000,
                       token_pattern=r'[a-zA-Z]{3,}' , ngram_range=(1,2))
X_train_dtm = vect.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_dtm = vect.transform(X_test)
nb_classifier.fit(X_train_dtm, y_train)
svm_classifier.fit(X_train_dtm, y_train)
lr_classifier.fit(X_train_dtm, y_train)
nb_predictions = nb_classifier.predict(X_test_dtm)
svm_predictions = svm_classifier.predict(X_test_dtm)
lr_predictions = lr_classifier.predict(X_test_dtm)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use plot_precision_recall_curve of sklearn.metrics to plot the precision recall curves for the methods as below:

```
nb_classifier = MultinomialNB()
svm_classifier = LinearSVC()
lr_classifier = LogisticRegression(multi_class="ovr")
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(df_train.data, df_train.label, test_size=0.2 , stratify = df_train['label'])
vect = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english', max_features=10000,
                       token_pattern=r'[a-zA-Z]{3,}' , ngram_range=(1,2))
X_train_dtm = vect.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_dtm = vect.transform(X_test)
nb_classifier.fit(X_train_dtm, y_train)

svm_classifier.fit(X_train_dtm, y_train)
lr_classifier.fit(X_train_dtm, y_train)
nb_predictions = nb_classifier.predict(X_test_dtm)
svm_predictions = svm_classifier.predict(X_test_dtm)
lr_predictions = lr_classifier.predict(X_test_dtm)

#plot Precision-Recall curve and display average precision-recall score
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve
from sklearn.metrics import plot_precision_recall_curve
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import average_precision_score

disp = plot_precision_recall_curve(svm_classifier, X_test_dtm, y_test) #display Precision-Recall curve for svm_classifier
average_precision = average_precision_score(y_test, svm_predictions)
print('Average precision-recall score for svm_classifier: {0:0.2f}'.format(
      average_precision))

disp = plot_precision_recall_curve(nb_classifier, X_test_dtm, y_test) #display Precision-Recall curve for nb_classifier
average_precision = average_precision_score(y_test, nb_predictions)
print('Average precision-recall score for nb_classifier: {0:0.2f}'.format(
      average_precision))

disp = plot_precision_recall_curve(lr_classifier, X_test_dtm, y_test) #display Precision-Recall curve for nb_classifier
average_precision = average_precision_score(y_test, lr_predictions)
print('Average precision-recall score for lr_classifier: {0:0.2f}'.format(
      average_precision))
```

Comment: Thank you. However I'm getting an import error for "plot_precision_recall_curve". I could import "precision_recall_curve"

Comment: What is your sklearn version? I am using version 0.22.1.

Comment: That maybe the issue. I'm  using 0.21.3 and I would try the solution after updating

Comment: Another option is to compute "precision" and "recall" using "precision_recall_curve" as "precision, recall, _ = precision_recall_curve(y_test,classifier_predictions)", and plot them using matplotlib.pyplot.

Comment: Thank you . I would try that too